# Convertendo arquivo para base64

Tags: javascript, angular

Ao tentar converter uma imagem para base64, não estou conseguindo atribuir a value corretamente para a variavél "retorno", somente consigo visualizar que não está atribuindo pois quando faço o console.log dentro da função anonima, a saida da conversão acontece corretamente, o que será que posso estar fazendo errado?

```
convertFileToBase64(file: File): string {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        var retorno = 'base64...';
        reader.readAsDataURL(file as Blob);
        reader.onloadend = () =>{ retorno = reader.result as string, console.log(retorno)} // aparece
        console.log(retorno) // não aparece
        return retorno
      }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema é que a função "readAsDataURL" é assíncrona e o método "onloadend" é chamado apenas quando a leitura do arquivo é concluída.
Portanto, o retorno da função "convertFileToBase64" é feito antes do final da leitura do arquivo e antes de atribuir o valor correto à variável retorno. Você pode usar uma "Promise" para resolver esse problema.

O código correto seria aproximadamente o seguinte:

```
convertFileToBase64(file: File): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file as Blob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64String = reader.result as string;
      console.log(base64String);
      resolve(base64String);
    };
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Opa, estou começando e não entendo muito do async e await, fiz aqui e deu certo, obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score -2):

Não podemos invocar `convertFileToBase64` e simplesmente pegar seu retorno, pois, como já foi explicado, ela processa o arquivo de forma assíncrona.

Então, uma outra abordagem, sem usar Promise, seria adicionar um segundo parâmetro à ela.

Este segundo parâmetro receberia um *callback*, uma função que será chamada quando a conversão estiver pronta.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');

function convertFileToBase64(file, callback) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onloadend = () => callback(reader.result);
}

input.addEventListener('change', () =>
  convertFileToBase64(input.files[0], (str) => console.log('', str))
);
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```